# Call async function in Pug/Jade

Tags: mongodb, pug

I want to get data from a MongoDB database by calling a function in pug. The function should return all Posts in an array.

The function finds all Posts in the database

```js
exports.getLastPosts = async () => {
  return Post.find();
};
```

Gets called on res.locals

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  res.locals.getLastPosts = pugHelper.getLastPosts;
  next();
});
```

And should then be stored in a variable in pug

```js
- var result = getLastPosts().then( result => result );
- console.log(result)
```

It then shows that the Promise is still pending

```js
Promise { <pending> }
```

Which is true because I can't use any async code in pug. It gives me this error when I'm using it:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (221:40)
```

So Pug seems to not understand keywords like async and await. But I don't know how to dynamically get Posts then without them.

Comment: Do you run the request before you compile Pug into HTML? I try do understand your workflow here so I can help you. When in your programs lifecycle does the request run?